# How to solve CORS issue for Google Cloud CDN & Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-cdn

I have created a Compute Engine - VM and have several websites installed.
Also, I have created Network services - Load balancing 
- Backend configuration: Created Backend services and join the instance group with the same VM above.
- Created Cloud CDN and config SSL certificate also done.

The website is https://united-athle.hk/
The CDN domain is https://cdn.ua.sugarproject.com

When I visit the website, the following CORS issue occurred
Access to resource at 'https://cdn.ua.sugarproject.com/wp-content/plugins/onesignal-free-web-push-notifications/sdk_files/manifest.json.php?gcm_sender_id=' from origin 'https://united-athle.hk' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have read Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS), 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin
but not really sure how-to config. My storage is in VM engine.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to configure the web server software running on your VM to include an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in its responses. For example, including an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://united-athle.hk` header would allow cross-origin requests from https://united-athle.hk/. https://enable-cors.org/server.html has information on how to do this for a variety of web server software.

Alternatively, you could serve both portions of your website from a single domain name, eliminating the need for cross-origin requests.

Comment: Hi elving,

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: setting doesn't work. It seem Google Cloud CDN rewrite the header.

Comment: Google Cloud CDN never rewrites Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers. Perhaps you are getting cache hits from a cache entry that was inserted into cache before you configured your web server software to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header? If so, you can invalidate your cache.

Comment: Hi elving, You are correct. the solution here https://enable-cors.org/server.html works for me now. It seem some caching issue previously. Now everything is fine. Thank you for your kindly help.